# Integrate a -3/2 power (for continuous charge distribution in physics)

Tags: calculus

How to integrate $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2+a^2)^3}}?$$
I've tried to use trig substitution, which I let $x=a\tan\theta$. I can simplify it to
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{a\sec^2\theta}{a^3\sqrt{(1+\tan\theta)^3}}d\theta=\int\frac{1}{a^2\cos^2\theta\sqrt{(1+\tan\theta)^3}}d\theta
\end{align*}
but what do I do next? Any help would be appreciated. (Also hints would be better than direct answers since I want to remember the method.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor error was made. You should have

$$\mathcal{I} := \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2+a^2)^3}} = \int\frac{a\sec^2\theta}{(a^2 \tan^2 \theta + a^2)^{3/2}}d\theta = \int\frac{a\sec^2\theta}{a^3 ( \tan^2 \theta + 1)^{3/2}}d\theta$$

Now use the identity $1 + \tan^2 x = \sec^2 x$.

Concluding should be easy from here.

Comment: If I didn't make any mistakes this time, I should have $$\frac{1}{a^2}\int\cos\theta~d\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{a^2}=\frac{x}{a^2\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}$$right? (I should specify that we assumed $C=0$.)

Comment: Yup, that's correct!